# Why can't Edge get correct keydown value in the case?

Tags: javascript

I have started learning JavaScript and wrote the following small game: when button is pressed, you get spinning circle, after several seconds you should press <kbd>a</kbd> or <kbd>l</kbd> keys to choose which player won the game. It works as expected in Firefox and in Chrome. But Microsoft Edge 44  EdgeHTML18 returns `event.key` as `undefined`.

```js
const startBtn = document.querySelector("span#stepIndicator button");
const spinner = document.querySelector("div#spinner");
const readyMakeStep = document.querySelector("span#stepIndicator p");
startBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  spinner.style.display = "inline-block";
  startBtn.disabled = true;
  let sleepSeconds = randomInteger();
  setTimeout(() => {
    readyMakeStep.style.display = "inline-block";
    spinner.style.display = "none";
    startBtn.style.display = "none";
    startBtn.disabled = false;
    document.addEventListener("keydown", waitKeyStroke);
  }, sleepSeconds * 1000);
});
let randomInteger = function() {
  return 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
};
let waitKeyStroke = function(e) {
  readyMakeStep.innerText = "Players Go!";
  switch (e.code) {
    case "KeyA":
      readyMakeStep.innerText = "Player 1 Won!";
      document.removeEventListener("keydown", waitKeyStroke);
      setTimeout(prepareField, 5000);
      break;
    case "KeyL":
      readyMakeStep.innerText = "Player 2 Won!";
      document.removeEventListener("keydown", waitKeyStroke);
      setTimeout(prepareField, 5000);
      break;
    default:
      alert(`Wrong Key: ${e.code}`);
  }
};
let prepareField = function() {
  startBtn.style.display = "inline-block";
  readyMakeStep.style.display = "none";
  readyMakeStep.innerText = "Players Go!";
};
```

```css
ul {
  padding-left: 0px;
}

li {
  display: inline;
}

body {
  background-color: indianred;
}

span {
  color: yellow;
  padding: 12px;
  border: 3px solid yellow;
  margin: 20px;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

span#stepIndicator {
  color: black;
  border: none;
}

span#stepIndicator button {
  font-family: "Times New Roman", "Times", "serif";
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: grey;
  border: none;
}

span#stepIndicator p {
  display: none;
  padding: 15px;
}

span#stepIndicator button:hover:enabled {
  background-color: aliceblue;
}

span#stepIndicator button:disabled {
  background-color: gray();
}

span#stepIndicator button:disabled {
  background-color: gray();
}

#spinner {
  display: none;
  margin: 50px;
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}


/* spinner animation from loading.io */

.lds-dual-ring {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}

.lds-dual-ring:after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  margin: 8px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 6px solid black;
  border-color: black transparent black transparent;
  animation: lds-dual-ring 1.2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes lds-dual-ring {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <span>Player 1: "A"</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span id="stepIndicator"><button>Start Game</button><p>Players Go!</p></span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span>Player 2: "L"</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="spinner">
  <p>Prepare to make step!</p>
  <div class="lds-dual-ring"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#search=event.key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just changed `e.code` with `e.which` , this returns an integer (key code) with each key :

1. a = 65.
2. l = 76.

```js
const startBtn = document.querySelector("span#stepIndicator button");
const spinner = document.querySelector("div#spinner");
const readyMakeStep = document.querySelector("span#stepIndicator p");
startBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  spinner.style.display = "inline-block";
  startBtn.disabled = true;
  let sleepSeconds = randomInteger();
  setTimeout(() => {
    readyMakeStep.style.display = "inline-block";
    spinner.style.display = "none";
    startBtn.style.display = "none";
    startBtn.disabled = false;
    document.addEventListener("keydown", waitKeyStroke);
  }, sleepSeconds * 1000);
});
let randomInteger = function() {
  return 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
};
let waitKeyStroke = function(e) {
  readyMakeStep.innerText = "Players Go!";
  switch (e.which) {
    case 65:
      readyMakeStep.innerText = "Player 1 Won!";
      document.removeEventListener("keydown", waitKeyStroke);
      setTimeout(prepareField, 5000);
      break;
    case 76:
      readyMakeStep.innerText = "Player 2 Won!";
      document.removeEventListener("keydown", waitKeyStroke);
      setTimeout(prepareField, 5000);
      break;
    default:
      alert(`Wrong Key: ${e.which}`);
  }
};
let prepareField = function() {
  startBtn.style.display = "inline-block";
  readyMakeStep.style.display = "none";
  readyMakeStep.innerText = "Players Go!";
};
```

```css
ul {
  padding-left: 0px;
}

li {
  display: inline;
}

body {
  background-color: indianred;
}

span {
  color: yellow;
  padding: 12px;
  border: 3px solid yellow;
  margin: 20px;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

span#stepIndicator {
  color: black;
  border: none;
}

span#stepIndicator button {
  font-family: "Times New Roman", "Times", "serif";
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: grey;
  border: none;
}

span#stepIndicator p {
  display: none;
  padding: 15px;
}

span#stepIndicator button:hover:enabled {
  background-color: aliceblue;
}

span#stepIndicator button:disabled {
  background-color: gray();
}

span#stepIndicator button:disabled {
  background-color: gray();
}

#spinner {
  display: none;
  margin: 50px;
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}


/* spinner animation from loading.io */

.lds-dual-ring {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}

.lds-dual-ring:after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  margin: 8px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 6px solid black;
  border-color: black transparent black transparent;
  animation: lds-dual-ring 1.2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes lds-dual-ring {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <span>Player 1: "A"</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span id="stepIndicator"><button>Start Game</button><p>Players Go!</p></span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span>Player 2: "L"</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="spinner">
  <p>Prepare to make step!</p>
  <div class="lds-dual-ring"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works as expected in Edge now, it looks like you saved me a lot of time! Really thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You're using [`KeyboardEvent.code`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code) which is not supported by Edge.

I'd suggest you to use [`KeyboardEvent.key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key), *e.g.*:

```js
const startBtn = document.querySelector("span#stepIndicator button");
const spinner = document.querySelector("div#spinner");
const readyMakeStep = document.querySelector("span#stepIndicator p");
startBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  spinner.style.display = "inline-block";
  startBtn.disabled = true;
  let sleepSeconds = randomInteger();
  setTimeout(() => {
    readyMakeStep.style.display = "inline-block";
    spinner.style.display = "none";
    startBtn.style.display = "none";
    startBtn.disabled = false;
    document.addEventListener("keydown", waitKeyStroke);
  }, sleepSeconds * 1000);
});
let randomInteger = function() {
  return 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
};
let waitKeyStroke = function(e) {
  readyMakeStep.innerText = "Players Go!";
  switch (e.key) {
    case "a":
    case "A":
      readyMakeStep.innerText = "Player 1 Won!";
      document.removeEventListener("keydown", waitKeyStroke);
      setTimeout(prepareField, 5000);
      break;
    case "l":
    case "L":
      readyMakeStep.innerText = "Player 2 Won!";
      document.removeEventListener("keydown", waitKeyStroke);
      setTimeout(prepareField, 5000);
      break;
    default:
      alert(`Wrong Key: ${e.key}`);
  }
};
let prepareField = function() {
  startBtn.style.display = "inline-block";
  readyMakeStep.style.display = "none";
  readyMakeStep.innerText = "Players Go!";
};
```

```css
ul {
  padding-left: 0px;
}

li {
  display: inline;
}

body {
  background-color: indianred;
}

span {
  color: yellow;
  padding: 12px;
  border: 3px solid yellow;
  margin: 20px;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

span#stepIndicator {
  color: black;
  border: none;
}

span#stepIndicator button {
  font-family: "Times New Roman", "Times", "serif";
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: grey;
  border: none;
}

span#stepIndicator p {
  display: none;
  padding: 15px;
}

span#stepIndicator button:hover:enabled {
  background-color: aliceblue;
}

span#stepIndicator button:disabled {
  background-color: gray();
}

span#stepIndicator button:disabled {
  background-color: gray();
}

#spinner {
  display: none;
  margin: 50px;
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}


/* spinner animation from loading.io */

.lds-dual-ring {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}

.lds-dual-ring:after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  margin: 8px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 6px solid black;
  border-color: black transparent black transparent;
  animation: lds-dual-ring 1.2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes lds-dual-ring {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <span>Player 1: "A"</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span id="stepIndicator"><button>Start Game</button><p>Players Go!</p></span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span>Player 2: "L"</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="spinner">
  <p>Prepare to make step!</p>
  <div class="lds-dual-ring"></div>
</div>
```

*N.B.* I've also added `case`s for <kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>L</kbd> to include uppercase chars in your `switch` statement.